# Run another pipeline from parameterised project when condition is true

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, parameterized

I have one project named `Project_1` and a pipeline named `Pipeline_1` in Jenkins. My `Project_1` is choice parameterized it has two choices named `option1` and `option2`. What I  have to do is when I will run `Project_1` with choice of `option1` then only `Project_1` will build but when I will run `Project_1` with choice of `option2` then `Project_1` will run and then my `Pipeline_1` will run. I have tried a Parameterized trigger but it didn't help me I select any option but my pipeline was always running with both options so Can I do this in `Jenkins`?

I have also checked this [link](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) for plugin info.

This is a screenshot of my Project_1:
[image: This is a screenshot of my Project_1]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SO. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/.../edit) your question and include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without code, your question is hard to understand. We can't understand what "Pipeline_1" means, or what you mean by "option2"

Also make sure to use [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code and preformatted text.

Comment: You may want to use a "Conditional step" to compare the condition and if it holds, trigger a job.

Comment: I just want to use a post-build trigger from **project_1** to **pipeline_1** with a particular choice(**Parameter**) of **project_1**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I used `Option=${Option}`  instead of this `$Options==cdn`.Then my problem was solved.